# High Javascript CPU use for webapp

Tags: javascript, performance

I've reached a point where I'm just fishing and hoping to catch something.

The Chrome performance tool shows nearly the whole CPU (so far as the tool detects, at least) is taken up by `timeupdate` events, with nothing else really firing. The event isn't referenced anywhere in the code or in its dependencies (via a Github search).

I reached a point where I ran `$("body").empty().off()` and `$(window).off()` to remove all events and any elements that could be doing anything, and inserted debugging code so I could loop through all functions and redefine them to `undefined`.

I also ran logging on `setInterval` and `setTimeout` so I could clear all of those.

I then worked through the Chrome inspector's "Event Listener" tab and manually removed all events.

I then finally run a cleanup helper that nukes everything else I could think of:

```
window.cleanupElements = ->
  $("*").off()
  $("style").remove()
  $("link").remove()
  $("script").remove()
  false
```

This white page with no body content, functions, timers, intervals, or events is still sitting pretty at 50%+ CPU use.

Ideas?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like browser plugins.

Comment: Unless you're doing freaking WEBGL (even that does not consume much CPU), its probably not your web app. Looks like browser plugins to me.

Comment: Hm, that's an interesting thought. Currently it's targeting a specific machine that I don't own until general release, so I'll investigate that. The CPU usage builds up as the app is used initially (eg, stays stable until user interacts and semi-deterministically increases with interaction), so I thought I maybe had overbound something or missed some recursive loop or interval or who knows what....

Comment: Use chrome task monitor. You'll get RAM and CPU usage per Tabs.

Comment: @WilomGfx that's what gives the CPU load (not the OS monitor)

Comment: I know, but it gives a good indication of whats going on ;) you even get browser extensions usages.

Comment: @WilomGfx yep, I know -- but all the CPU in in the tab itself, see http://imgur.com/a/zZcsM